# Returning 10 most frequently used words in a document in O(n)

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity

How can I design an algorithm which can return the 10 most frequently used words in a document in O(n) time? If additional space can be used.

I can parse and place the words in a hash map with count . But next I have to sort the values to get the most frequent ones . Also I have to have a mapping btw the values -> Key which cannot be maintained since values may be repeating.

So how can I solve this ?

Comment: Sounds like Homework. What have you tried?

Comment: What is `n`? The number of words in the text? Or the number of characters in the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be done in O(n) if you use the correct data structure.

Consider a `Node`, consisting of 2 things:

- A counter (initially set to 0).
- An array of 255 (or whatever number of characters) pointers to `Node`. All the pointers are initially set to `NULL`.

Create a root node. Define a "current" `Node` pointer, set it to root node initially.
Then walk through all the characters of the document and do the following:

- If the next characters is not a space - pick the appropriate pointer from the array of the current node. If it's `NULL` - allocate it. The current `Node` pointer is updated.
- If it's a space (or whatever word delimiter) - increment the counter of the "current" `Node`. Then reset the "current" `Node` pointer to point to the root node.

By such you build a tree in O(n). Every element (both node and leave) denote a specific word, together with its counter.

Then transverse the tree to find the node with the largest counter. It's also O(n), since the number of elements in the tree is not bigger than O(n).

**Update:**

The last step is not mandatory. Actually the most common word may be updated during the character processing.
The following is a pseudo-code:

```
struct Node
{
    size_t m_Counter;
    Node* m_ppNext[255];
    Node* m_pPrev;

    Node(Node* pPrev) :m_Counter(0)
    {
        m_pPrev = pPrev;
        memset(m_ppNext, 0, sizeof(m_ppNext));
    }
    ~Node()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _countof(m_ppNext) i++)
            if (m_ppNext[i])
                delete m_ppNext[i];
    }

};

Node root(NULL);
Node* pPos = &root;
Node* pBest = &root;
char c;

while (0 != (c = GetNextDocumentCharacter()))
{
    if (c == ' ')
    {
        if (pPos != &root)
        {
            pPos->m_Counter++;

            if (pBest->m_Counter < pPos->m_Counter)
                pBest = pPos;

            pPos = &root;
        }
    } else
    {
        Node*& pNext = pPos->m_ppNext[c - 1];
        if (!pNext)
            pNext = new Node(pPos);
        pPos = pNext;
    }
}

// pBest points to the most common word. Using pBest->m_pPrev we iterate in reverse order through its characters
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple algorithm:

- Read one word at a time through the document. **O(n)**
- Build a HashTable using each word. **O(n)**

  - Use the word as the key. **O(1)**
  - Use the number of times you've seen this word as the value. **O(1)**
  - (e.g. If you are adding the key to the hashtable, then value is 1; if you already have the key in the hashtable, increase its associated value by 1) **O(1)**
- Create a pair of arrays of size 10 (i.e. String words[10] / int count[10], or use a < Pair >), use this pair to keep track of the 10 most frequent words and their word counts in the next step. **O(1)**
- Iterate through the completed HashTable once: **O(n)**

  - If the current word has a higher word count than an entry in the array pair, replace that particular entry and shift everything down 1 slot. **O(1)**
- Output the pair of arrays. **O(1)**

**O(n)** Run-time.

**O(n)** Storage for the HashTable + Arrays

(Side note: You can just think of HashTable as a dictionary: a way to store key:value pairs where keys are unique. Technically HashMaps imply asynchronous access, and HashTable imply synchronous.)

Comment: I'm curious how "searching the map" for the new word, in order to determine if you've seen that word before isn't O(logN)?  Since you have to do that for each word, isn't building the full hashtable O(NlogN)?

Comment: The complexity of creating hash tables is O(1) amortized (actually O(alpha), but that's splitting hairs)

Comment: Yes, that's true, only on direct inserts... you want to insert only if the word hasn't been seen before.  If it HAS, then you have to find it in the map to increment the count for it.  THat's a map GET, which is O(logN), not O(1)

Comment: @BillJames I think that's the point of the Hash - it will provide O(1) insertion because all words of the same form will collide in one spot. Then you update the counter at that location

Comment: Hashing a word in `O(1)` - that's quite a stretch. Of course, it all depends on what the original statement of the problem allows to consider as `O(1)`, but nevertheless...

Comment: @EliAlgranti I see what you're talking about with the amortized, but that assumes a number of buckets in your hashmap nearly equivalent to the number of words being stored, which seems an unfair assumption.

Comment: @AndreyT why do you claim that hashing in O(1) is a stretch? Granted, it's not 1 op, but if you hash and use no collision technique (all you do is increment a counter), surely that is O(1)

Comment: Depends on the hash implementation. There are implementations where all operations O(alpha) amortized assuming a good hash function (i.e. uniform over the range of inputs, with random inputs.) Maps with O(log(n)) complexity are tree based maps (not hashes). Their advantage is they are always O(log(n)), while an unfortunate run of a hash may be O(n). They are also much simpler to implement which may account for better actual performance.

Comment: @AK4749 That presumes a perfect hash (which is probably easy enough for words), and the ability to use the hash as an index to an array.  Either you get a good no-collide hash, or you get a small set of hashes, usually not both.

Comment: @AK4749: A "word" is generally assumed to be a sequence of `m` characters and natural complexity of hashing a "word" is `O(m)`. To interpret a "word" as an atomic `O(1)`-hashable entity is what I called a stretch. It is just too big of a simplification.

Comment: AndreyT is correct hashing a word is O(m) (m number of characters in the word) so over the whole document hashing will be O(n). Same for the comparison required when retrieving the word from the hash and storing in the arrays. Many of the O(1) operations are O(1) word, but O(n) characters. The algorithm is still O(n) characters.

Comment: @AndreyT For practical applications, I think you can assume a few things. Suppose we start with the document in English (it can be multi-lingual, but the point remains), then we have some fixed upper bound of available possible words. Devise a hash scheme with fairly even distribution. Then time for collision resolution via chaining, for example, can have a constant time upperbound. The big idea is that while n can grow to infinity, m - the # of possible words is likely fixed.

Comment: @BillJames `HashMap.get()` is O(1), not O(logN). ["This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic operations (get and put)".](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Answer (score 2):

The fastest approach is to use a radix tree. You can store the count of words at the leaf of the radix tree. Keep a separate list of the 10 most frequent words and their occurrence count along with a variable that stores the threshold value necessary to get into this list. Update this list as items are added to the tree.

Comment: Actually your answer is correct and precise, which is guaranteed to work in O(n), unlike the most scored straightforward solution with the hashtable, which can *theoretically* work in O(1), but practically - not guaranteed.

Comment: First create Radix Tree(or just trie) and count occurrences of each word, create a Min Heap of size 10, then scan the radix tree.

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining a map of (word,count) will be O(n).

Once the map is built, iterate over the keys and retrieve ten most common keys.

O(n) + O(n)

-- 
But not exactly happy with this soln coz of the extra amount of external memory needed.

Comment: "Keep a map" not really explanatory.   How exactly would you do that in O(n) without having to search the map over and over, each of which is a logN search?

Comment: A map implentation lookup is O(1) so finding a key in a map. Getting its count and updating it , is O(n), for the whole document

Comment: @SajitKunnumkal isn't lookup in maps O(logN)?

Comment: Depends on what we are calling as map here. If its a hash implementation of a map eg (HashMap) its O(1)

Comment: yes, it is.  It's not necessarily log2, but it's logX depending on the bucket count.

Comment: Ok, they're referring to a hashmap that has N buckets or more... which is basically an array.  I don't believe that's a valid assumption

Answer (score 0):

I would use a ArrayList and a HashTable.

Here is the algorithm I am thinking of,

```
Loop through all the word in the document.

if (HashTable.contains(word) )
    increment count for that word in the HashTable;
else
    ArrayList.add(word);
    HashTable.add(word);
    word count in HashTable = 1;
```

After looping through the whole document,

```
Loop through ArrayList<word>
    Retrieve the word count for that word from the HashTable;
    Keep a list of the top 10 words;
```

The running time should be O(n) to construct the HashTable and ArrayList.
Making the top 10 list should be O(m), where m is the number of unique words.
O(n+m) where n>>m  --> O(n)